# What is a Self-Normalized Process?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, martingale

I came across a vast literature by Victor H. de la Peña (you can find the book [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Self-Normalized-Processes-Statistical-Applications-Probability/dp/3540856358/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=self-normalized%20processes&qid=1633341208&sr=8-1)) that concern *self-normalized processes*, but I am struggling to understand the definition of said processes! What are these processes? Is it a simply a process for which the variables are demeaned and divided by their standard deviation? In which case, how is that a process?

Comment: Could you please quote the reference you are referring to? It helps if your question is self-contained.

Comment: @mhdadk I have edited the question to reflect this.